# What's the simplest way to obtain the current weather and forecast for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, weather-api

Using iOS 4, what's the quickest way to obtain the user's current location (assuming they grant it to you) and use it to obtain the current weather conditions and forecast?

I'm mainly interested in solutions that don't have any licensing restrictions and don't use APIs that will ban the app from the app store.  Many of the other related questions posted on SO have these limited solutions.

Thanks so much in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

NOAA has free webservice

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/

It's updated once an hour.